# Long Execution Time for Cumulative Sum in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum, sqlperformance

I work on a C# project with SQL Server 2008.

In my project I want to get some records with under SQL statement:

```
WITH tbl_tmp
AS (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row
        ,d.doc_amount AS amount
    FROM docs AS d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN docs_items AS di ON di.doc_id = d.doc_id
    WHERE di.branch_id = 1
        AND di.doc_date >= 20150101
        AND di.doc_date <= 20151201
        AND SUBSTRING(CAST(d.acc_id AS VARCHAR), 1, 4) = 1130
    ORDER BY di.doc_date ASC
        ,di.doc_number ASC
        ,d.docrow ASC
    )

SELECT row,
       amount,
       (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN (SUM(amount)) < 0
                    THEN ABS(SUM(amount))
                ELSE 0
                END
        FROM tbl_tmp AS _tmp
        WHERE _tmp.row <= tbl_tmp.row
        ) AS sum_debtor
    ,(
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN (SUM(amount)) > 0
                    THEN ABS(SUM(amount))
                ELSE 0
                END
        FROM tbl_tmp AS _tmp
        WHERE _tmp.row <= tbl_tmp.row
        ) AS sum_creditor
FROM tbl_tmp;
```

but execution time for getting records from SQL Server is very long (for example 28 second for get 2207 records, whereas my PC is Core-i7 & 8Gb Ram)

How can get results in faster time?

**PS:** Even I removing «**sum_creditor** column» from SQL Statement, my execution time will 14 seconds for 2207 records that is too long for me.

---

**Edit:**

my output results is like this:

```
row    |amount      |sum_debtor     |sum_debtor
-------------------------------------------------
1      |1000        |1000           |0
2      |500         |1500           |0
3      |-2500       |0              |1000
4      |6000        |5000           |0
5      |-3000       |2000           |0 
.
.
.
.
2206   |8000        |13000          |0
2207   |-20000      |0              |7000
```

Comment: Do you really want to end the search at Dec 1 or Dec 31? di.doc_date <= 20151201

Comment: i store date like that yyyymmdd, and What's different? the problem is something else.

Comment: I meant, your criteria ends Dec 1st. Usually with a start date of Jan 1st, and end date of Dec would be Dec 31 :)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

- `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT` is unnecessary. If you want to select all records, just do `SELECT`. The query optimizer should be smart enough to leave this out, but you never know
- I'm doing a bit of assuming here because you don't list any sample data, but it looks like the CTE is pulling just a row number and an amount. It then looks like you want to pull two counts, debtors and creditors, where each negative amount is a debtor count and each positive is a creditor. If that's the case, having two nested `SELECT`s is unnecessary, as is the ROW_NUMBER() in the CTE. If my assumptions are correct, I'd wager the `_tmp.row <= tbl_tmp.row` is absolutely killing your performance. Something like this should give you what you're looking for:

  ```
  SELECT 
      SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) debtor
      , SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) creditor
  FROM tbl_tmp
  ```
- Your question is tagged SQL Server. If that is the case, the speed of your computer has nothing to do with query execution times. The time the results take to come back from the server depend exclusively on the performance of the SQL Server (hardware, resources available, competing TSQL queries, applicable indexes and their fragmentation, etc). Your computer sends the query to the server then does nothing until the server sends a response. Having the fastest desktop computer in the world won't make your query execute faster (unless you're running an Express instance on your local machine).

Comment: thanks,
1- i most ordering columns in tbl_tmp, so i most using `TOP 100 PERCENT` statement, because without this SQL server show this error: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`
2- i use `_tmp.row <= tbl_tmp.row` because i want cumulative sum or running total, not regular sum, for more information about cumulative sum see: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/cumulative-tables-graphs.html 
3- yes, i am using express version and the SQL server installed on my local machine,

Comment: I see. I misunderstood what you meant because of the use of debtor and creditor. I will edit my example. An example of some of your source data as well as your expected out put would still be very helpful in answering this question.

Comment: i edited my question & and added output records sample.